# How to make batch ffmpeg with this codes?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, windows

How i batch render with ffmpeg with this code on windows? Codes work well.

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i background_image.png -i mainmovie.mov -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[V1]; [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=800:452[V2]; [V1][V2]overlay=shortest=1:x=240:y=134" out.mov
```

Comment: See: http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/19860/batch-conversion-into-a-new-folder-with-ffmpeg